# How I can feed to ElasticSearch with Logstash or curl?

Tags: json, curl, elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to import all the json into my elasticsearch. I have tried `curl` command for that purpose, but of no use as it start giving parsing errors.
This is what I tried:

```
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test" -d "@test.json"
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test/_bulk" -d "@test.json"
curl -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test/_bulk" --data-binary "@test.json"
curl -s -XPOST "http://localhost:9200/test/_bulk" --data-binary "@test.json"
```

And many other attempts. But What I got is `Parsing error`. Hence would like to know what is the way out to feed to elasticsearch all my records?
Also, if someone can help me solve it with logstash then it will be a great help. Kindly, let me know the best possible suggestion.
Here is the sample data in a JSON and it is separated with a newline, probably. [Sample Data](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzQ6rtO2VN95cmF0QmltckN4Ymc/view?usp=sharing)
Here is the error:

```
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "parse_exception",
        "reason" : "Failed to derive xcontent"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "parse_exception",
    "reason" : "Failed to derive xcontent"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your json like this:

```
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type" } }
{"data":...}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type" } }
{"data":...}
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type" } }
{"data":...}
```

Then you can run:

```
curl -s -H "Content-Type: application/x-ndjson" -XPOST localhost:9200/_bulk --data-binary "@test.json"
```

Read more about [Bulk API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.3/docs-bulk.html).

If you wish to do that with Logstash, you can use a [stdin input](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.3/plugins-inputs-stdin.html) with a [json filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.3/plugins-filters-json.html), then an [elasticsearch output](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/5.3/plugins-outputs-elasticsearch.html). Something like (not tested):

```
input {
  stdin { }
}

filter { 
  json { 
    source => "message" 
  }

  mutate {
    remove_field => [ "message" ]
  }
}

output {
  elasticsearch {
  }
}
```

Then launch:

```
cat test.json | bin/logstash -f logstash.conf
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: BTW if you split your file in multiple files, like one JSON document per file, you can use https://github.com/dadoonet/fscrawler project.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139639/discussion-between-dadoonet-and-jaffer-wilson).